Horizontal sparklines with negative numbers in G. Sheets
I am trying to create a sparkline formula in Google Sheets for a horizontal bar with negative numbers, for a project budget tracker.
The idea is that the horizontal bar is centered in a cell, so it can go right (green color) for positive numbers, and left (red color) for negative numbers, while keeping yellow color for inbetween. Maximum and minimum should be for each cell different, based on the approved budget for that line, so I would prefer a formula which I can drag for the other cells.
The bars should look something like this:

In the provided document you can see my attempt for the formula.
Remark: I use European delimiters, so for more complex formulas it can get confusing where to put ";" or "", for the level of knowledge I currently possess.
Thank you in advance for the help!
EDIT:
Perhaps a solution in two columns could be possible. With if function, where negative numbers go to the left in the first column, and if the number is positive goes to the right in the second column.

maybe this could help...

Thanks!
I have already tried this approach, but the problem is that max and min for this one are the same for the same set. I need a different set for each cell.

you could somehow try and showcase how your ideal output would look like & maybe that would help the folks here to get a clear picture on what is really expected in this scenario and all

Thanks for the suggestion. I made an edit, put a picture of how the bars should look like.

added 2 column approach in your test sheet for you to check out.


Approach 1
=map(A2:A;C2:C;lambda(a;c;if(or(a="";c="");;
 sparkline(let(Σ;c/a;hstack(1+min(max(Σ;-1);0);min(0;max(Σ;-1));max(0;Σ)));{"charttype"\"bar";"max"\2;"color1"\"white";"color2"\"#ec417a";"color3"\"#63d297"}))))


Approach 2 (2-column approach)
=map(A2:A11;C2:C11;lambda(a;c;let(Σ;c/a;if(Σ>0;
 hstack(;sparkline(Σ;{"charttype"\"bar";"max"\1;"color1"\"#63d297"}));
 hstack(sparkline(Σ;{"charttype"\"bar";"max"\1;"color1"\"#ec417a";"rtl"\true});))))) 



That works great. I like the second approach better (it is visually better). Is there a way to make the white color fully transparent, so that left of the bar is instead of white color, just the one that is in background? I would match the color myself in the formula, but what I really need is full transparency, because the table has conditional formatting (alternating colors). If there is no code for full transparency, other approach could be having formula that I can drag down, and then change the color where needed.

I am unaware of a transparency parameter. to drag just use =map(A2;C2; in place of =map(A2:A11;C2:C11;

I found a problem in case where a negative number is larger than the approved budget. Could there be an addition to the existing formula that if the negative number is large that it stays at maximum on the left, and not disappear?

Recreate it in your test sheet and I can check it out

In a new spreadsheet you can find the data and I marked where the problem is. Thank you for the support!

test out the updated formula added in Column_L

Based on the documentation:SPARKLINE, the Sparkline function in Google Sheets does not include the positioning of the sparkline within the cell through the formula itself. (Though it has the Right-to-Left feature which may be of use to you) Instead, it only provides options for the sparkline's appearance, such as chartype, which includes bar charts as you mentioned, color, formatting, and so on.
Additionally, Bar charts can only have two colors used in a cell. How many colors can a Google Sheets sparkline have?
On the other hand, You may opt for an alternative method if it's necessary.
Sharing here another link that may help you:
Everything you ever wanted to know about Sparklines in Google Sheets
Note: I am not affiliated nor the owner of the site.
